# How to determine device orientation in Custom Keyboard

Tags: ios8, custom-keyboard, ios8-extension

I am building a custom keyboard for iOS8.
I want my keyboard to support portrait and landscape modes.
How do I determine the device orientation?
Getting device orientation doesn't currently work well in custom keyboards.

Comment: what exactly is the problem? what problems are you facing?

Comment: When My keyboard is in landscape mode How I will determine that the keyboard extension is in landscape mode.

Comment: i edited your question and answered it. hope i helped

Answer (score 1):

`willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` can be used, although they are deprecated in iOS 8. Their replacement, `willTransitionToTraitCollection`, isn't called upon rotation though likely because the trait collection doesn't change for the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the standard method for determining device orientation doesn't work yet in iOS8 custom keyboards.

You can determine the device orientation by checking the ratios between the width and the height of the device.
height > width = portrait
width > height = landscape

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, InterfaceOrientationType)
{
    InterfaceOrientationTypePortrait,
    InterfaceOrientationTypeLandscape
};

- (InterfaceOrientationType)orientation
{
    InterfaceOrientationType result;

    if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width < [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)
    {
        result = InterfaceOrientationTypePortrait;
    }
    else
    {
        result = InterfaceOrientationTypeLandscape;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: How I will get the current mode for custom keyboard??